# How can I prevent a specific script from loading on specific IPs?

Tags: javascript, dns, ip, addthis

I've just started using AddThis on my site which involves putting a short snippet of asynchronous JS on all of your pages.

Each time the script is called it counts as a pageview and you have an allowance of X number of pageviews.

Currently we're racking up hundreds of "visits" through testing and working on the site which is a waste.

So is there any way to stop this script from getting called or loaded at our IP addresses?

Comment: With a bit of server-side code you can simply chose whether or not to include the script in the pages by checking the IP address.  What server-side language do you use?

Comment: Apache, so C. Website is built in php. Would this be server-side code or just on the back-end of the site?

Comment: In the pages that include the script, simply add a function to check the IP address of the client, and then include the script if it's not your IP.  I'm not a PHP coder so I can't help you with that, other than googling and finding what you need.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct support for obtaining the ip address of the machine from JavaScript. But little bit server side code and AJAX you should be able to obtain the Ip address. So write a WebMethod which will retrieve the IP Address from the Request object and return it to caller. For AJAX you can use the very excellent JQuery library.

Comment: I fpund one link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Detect-Find-Client-IP-Address-using-JavaScript-jQuery.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but this should be done completely on the server.  There is no need for ajax at all.

Comment: hey, I just want to say that if we want to handle it at client side, Then we can the pass the ip address to client side via ajax call. There on success, we can match the ip address and decide whether to run the visitor counter  function or not. if i am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that it can be done that way, but it isn't the correct way to do it.  It simply needs 1 check in the PHP file that includes the addthis script.  What you're suggesting is overkill.